# How to refresh a web page automatically every specified period of time

Tags: asp.net, html, dom

I am using asp.net to develop a website, and I want one of my web pages to refresh every 5 seconds when requested; how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you add a `meta` tag to the page's header?

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh):

> Place inside  to refresh page
>   after 5 seconds:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
> ```
>
> Redirect to http://example.com/ after
>   5 seconds:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://example.com/" />
> ```
>
> Redirect to http://example.com/
>   immediately:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/" />
> ```

Also see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)

Comment: I'm doing this too right now but the problem is there is no error handling with this method.  If the page refreshes and there is some sort of error on the page then it stops and no more refreshing.  Is there any way to invoke error handling with this way so that you can decide to keep refreshing or stop with a friendly error?

Comment: Sounds like you should probably be doing something in ajax instead of page refreshes.

Answer (score 7):

It should be noted that if your page is a largeish one, people on slow connections may never finish downloading the page before it refreshes.

If it is a large page and this is a concern, consider using JavaScript.

Placing this before the closing `</body>` tag should do the trick:

```
<script>setTimeout('window.location.href = window.location.href', 5000);</script>
```

Comment: +1 This is a very valid point and I have encountered this situation before.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the tag for the meta refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Like ongle, I would suggest:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that much of your page may not change, you may want to consider an AJAX panel for that, given that ASP.NET supports it.

Check out [the tutorial](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/tutorials/TimerControlWithUpdatePanelsTutorial.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a meta tag or javascript as other suggested, but be careful when doing that.  If you do it wrong you can break your viewstate.  A better option might be to use the timer control and do a postback from there.

Comment: +1 Another very good point in cases where view state is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

alo you can use this code in behind code like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", " setTimeout('window.location.href = window.location.href', 1000);", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its also worth to note if you are doing this and have a master page you need to do this in the master page not the asp content page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://example.com/" />
```