# How to make multiple users edit a text at the same time without losing data?

Tags: multithreading, web-services, web, concurrency, thread-safety

Let's say we have an web application that allows multiple users to write in a text field. For instance: let's say that we have user1 and user2 using the application simultaneously.

1. At the beginning the text field is empty.
2. User1 writes "Hello world" and clicks the send button.
3. After that, both user1 and user2 see the "Hello world" on the text field.
4. User2 erases the "world" word and writes "galaxy" then sends the message.
5. Now both user1 and user2 see "Hello galaxy".
6. And so on......

But there are cases that data will be lost, principally when both users are editing the text field at the same time. How can I do to fix this problem? Is there a way? If not, what is the best way to do something like that? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways that I would think would work the best:

One of the ways that this can be fixed primarily is simply by restricting two people to be editing the same piece of code at the same time.  One person will be restricted to the part they are working on and another to a different part.  Then, one person could comment on another's piece of code for advice or something that they should change.  However, this does make collaboration quite difficult, and most likely it will be hard for you to give feedback.  There can still be some good collaboration, though, and you will be able to work together without any of these problems. In addition, when only one person is on the collaboration site, there could be full access.

In addition, you could make it so that any changes are immediately saved and then discarded soon after.  That way, if two changes are recorded on the same piece of text in quick succession, then the computer could report that there may have been some problems, and the two users can sort out there changes.

Hope this was helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

Every user couldn't seen the newly changed text until they don't `refresh` the page....

Unless you set to [refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987125/how-to-refresh-a-web-page-automatically-every-specified-period-of-time.) the page with specific time